# how to access variables in-behind xaml code from another in-behind xaml code

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

i'm trying to make like a messenger program WPF
my solution contains app.xaml & app.xaml.cs , mainwindow.xaml & mainwindow.xaml.cs
and another two xaml pages first for connecting , second for messenger core { contacts , status , .. etc }
i hava a library of agsxmpp that helps me to connect
where is the best .cs file to define and initialize connection
and how to access it (( and its event handlers )) from another .cs file

btw this problem always face me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A default WPF template will look like this with a **StartupUri** property.

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    StartupUri="Window1.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

You need to remove **StartupUri** and use the **Startup** event instead so that you can create your main window manually.

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Startup="Application_Startup">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>


namespace WpfApplication1
{

    public partial class App : Application
    {
        private XmppClientConnection _client = new XmppClientConnection ( );

        private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            var mainWindow = new Window1();
            mainWindow.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can add a new constructor to the Window1 class so you can pass it the object you need to reference.

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    private XmppClientConnection _client;

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Window1(XmppClientConnection client):this()
    {
        _client = client;
    }
}
```

Like so:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    _client = new XmppClientConnection();
    var mainWindow = new Window1(client);
    mainWindow.Show();
}
```

Comment: @panamack : thanks for your comment but you don't understand me at all
where can i put this code

**`public  XmppClientConnection Client = new XmppClientConnection ( );`**
to access it form other cs classes

Comment: @Ahmed I will update my code to make it clear in that context.

Comment: @Ahmed you can either instantiate XmppClientConnection at the entry point of your application and pass it around as you create objects that need it or an alternative would be to wrap it in a [singleton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) and reference the singleton from any class that needed a reference to it.

Comment: @panamak : sorry for interruption but what if i create event handlers for the connection in App.cs and the event happened in window1.cs would it will be handled?

Comment: @Ahmed if you had subscribed event handlers to your XmppClientConnection object in App.cs and then passed the same instance to Window1 whereupon it fired an event then yes the App.cs event handlers would handle the event, along with any other handlers that you had subsequently subscribed to it.